# Add GPS data to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiimage

I have a custom in-app build camera. This camera can take photos and videos and after this it saves the photos to the user library. I now want to add the current location from the iPhone while the picture was made to the image.
I found this:

```
func addLocationToImage(image: UIImage, location: CLLocation) throws -> UIImage {
    guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) else {
        throw NSError(domain: "error", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to get JPEG data from image."])
    }

    let metadata = NSMutableDictionary()
    let gpsDict = NSMutableDictionary()

    let latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude = location.coordinate.longitude

    gpsDict[(kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude as String)] = abs(latitude)
    gpsDict[(kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitudeRef as String)] = latitude < 0.0 ? "S" : "N"
    gpsDict[(kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude as String)] = abs(longitude)
    gpsDict[(kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitudeRef as String)] = longitude < 0.0 ? "W" : "E"

    metadata[(kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary as String)] = gpsDict

    guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, nil) else {
        throw NSError(domain: "error", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to create image source from data."])
    }

    let uti = CGImageSourceGetType(source)!
    let mutableData = NSMutableData(data: data)

    guard let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(mutableData, uti, 1, nil) else {
        throw NSError(domain: "error", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to create image destination."])
    }

    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source, 0, metadata)

    guard CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) else {
        throw NSError(domain: "error", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to write image with metadata to data."])
    }

    guard let imageWithGPSData = UIImage(data: mutableData as Data) else {
        throw NSError(domain: "error", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to create image from data with GPS metadata."])
    }

    return imageWithGPSData
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.
Have I done something wrong, because **the location is there** but it **doesn't get added to the image**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImage` doesn't have any metadata. Once you go from the updated data (with the added GPS info) back to `UIImage`, that metadata is lost.

Update your method to return the updated `Data` (`mutableData`) instead of a `UIImage`. Then you can persist that data as needed so it's saved with the new metadata.

Comment: Thanks for your help! And how can I save an image without it being an UIImage to the user photos library? I think I can't just save Data, right?

Comment: You can. Look into [`PHAssetCreationRequest addResource(with:data:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcreationrequest/1622684-addresource).

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the easiest way** I found to set the location of an image before saving it to user's Photos Library (Photos app).

When creating a new `PHAssetCreationRequest`, **you can directly add the location** to `PHAssetCreationRequest` like this:

```
// get the user's location in whatever way you like
let location = CLLocation(latitude: 7.2906, longitude: 80.6337) 


let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()

// add location data
creationRequest.location = location
```

That's it. Now when you save the image data, those location data will also be added to the image.